# Is it possible to update existing Github repository wth another local repository?

Tags: git, github, heroku, repository

I've created a basic app with **Node** backend and **React** frontend. I created a github repository and updated it with the changes. But due to configuration issues, I couldn't get the server working on Heroku.

So I searched through and found [this](https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node) starter-pack of *create-react-app with a custom Node server on Heroku* . I cloned it and updated the project. Now I hosted it on Heroku and it's working perfectly fine. Now I need it to push it to Github. I need to push it to the existing repository I've been working on(as it's the same project, just with working build on Heroku). As I'm on different projects (folders), how can I completely update my Github repository with this project ?

I have fine understanding with Git. When it comes to something like this(completely updating existing repository with new local repository) I'm getting confused. So, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind overriding completely your GitHub history with your new local repo, you can try:

```
git push --mirror
```

That will force update your branches.

Comment: I need to have the commit history (not the changes, but the number of commits). Yea, It should be override the repository with current project. I'll try this.

Comment: I thought this worked. But this isn't what I wanted. I wanted to show number of commits of previous project and push the new project to the same repo with a commit message like `this is why I moved to this build` . Anyway, it's fine.